How to enable DEBUG level for unit tests in Springboot 3.1.10?
I need to enable debug mode globally, so output from the application classes is logged in both application and unit tests.
I enabled DEBUG mode in src\main\resources\application.properties and it works only in the app, but in the tests.
BTW, initially there was no logging in tests whatsoever due to No SLF4J providers were found, so I had to add slf4j-simple to pom.xml to fix that, but the log level for test remains at INFO level.
I've tried to copy application.properties into src\test\resources, but it didn't help.
My app is using java.util.logging.
Would be grateful for any suggestions.

Since unit tests are not running under spring boot and you are using slf4j-simple, you will need to configure Maven surefire to set the correct log level in pom.xml:
     <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.2.5</version>
        <configuration>   
          <systemPropertyVariables>
            <!-- logging (also src/test/resources/simplelogger.properties) -->
            <org.slf4j.simpleLogger.defaultLogLevel>DEBUG</org.slf4j.simpleLogger.defaultLogLevel>
 </systemPropertyVariables>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>

You can find other properties to fine tune simple logger in the official docs: https://www.slf4j.org/api/org/slf4j/simple/SimpleLogger.html
P.S. From experience, every project using slf4j-simple ends up switching to Logback, except in one-off educational exercises.

That helped, thanks a lot! Wondering though what's wrong with using slf4j-simple?

If my answer helped, please, upvote and mark as answered.
The need to manage log properties in resources/... is not very robust in production, compared to external logback.xml. You don't want to re-release your software to change log level. There are ways to go around it, but mostly people switch to logback.

Just upvoted. Sorry, couldn't do it earlier since I didn't have sufficient reputation to do so, but as of today I have finally earned enough reputation to be able to vote :)
And thanks for clarification about logback. I'll keep that in mind.

Add the following line to your application.properties file : (src/test/resources/application.properties)
logging.level.YOUR_PACKAGE_NAME=DEBUG
If you want to enable DEBUG logging for the entire project, add the following line :
logging.level.root=DEBUG

Thanks, but as I mentioned in my original post, I've already tried it with not much success
